# Run-time error '2455': You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property Form/Report

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am working on an Access DB made by someone else, and I am quite new to access. I have noticed this issue occuring when I click into datasheet view for a form with multiple subforms. Debugging the code gives the following in VBA:

```
If Me.Detail.Visible = False Then Me.Detail.Visible = True
If Me.txtusefees = False Then
Me.frmTournamentNominations.Form.Label35.Visible = False
Me.frmTournamentNominations.Form.cboFeeType.Visible = True
Me.frmTournamentNominations.Form.txtfeestopay.Visible = False
Me.frmTournamentNominations.Form.Command98.Visible = False
Me.frmTournamentNominations.Form.Fees.Visible = False
Me.frmTournamentNominations.Form.Label36.Visible = False
Me.frmTournamentNominations.Form.Label26.Visible = False
Me.frmTournamentNominations.Form.Label71.Visible = True

Else
Me.frmTournamentNominations.Form.FeeTypeLabel.Visible = True
Me.frmTournamentNominations.Form.Label36.Visible = True
Me.frmTournamentNominations.Form.cboFeeType.Visible = True
Me.frmTournamentNominations.Form.txtfeestopay.Visible = True
Me.frmTournamentNominations.Form.Command98.Visible = True
Me.frmTournamentNominations.Form.Fees.Visible = True
Me.frmTournamentNominations.Form.Label26.Visible = True
Me.frmTournamentNominations.Form.Label71.Visible = False

End If
```

The code errors out on Me.frmTournamentNominations.Form.FeeTypeLabel.Visible = True, despite the fact the label is in the subform. I have tried moving the label from header to footer. This issue is occuring for all properties. This is also happening on multiple other forms too. I have also expanded the sections so all of the properties are visible for the form to reference.

I have been looking at this issue for a while and any advice would be appreciated. I'm also not overly confident with access so if you could break down your steps that would be great.

Comment: what is the error message, what is the structure of the forms and subforms and the mentioned controls.

Comment: `frmTournamentNominations` is name of subform container control? You are using datasheet/subdatasheet?